# Does Java handle cURL differently?

Tags: java, curl, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm trying to execute a POST request using `curl` in order to do some authorization. The expected result is a token which will be provided in the `Location response header`

### Issue

- If I execute the command from within my bash, it'll work just fine (= with redirections etc.)
- If I execute the **exact same command** (really just copy&paste) in my `Java` application, I get a slightly different result ( = missing token in the `Location response header`)

### Expected result

Token located in the `Location response header`, like `Location: /https://localhost:4200/token=123`

### Actual result

Some kind of error, like `Location: my.policy`

### Command

This is the basic structure of the command. Basically, it is a POST request with some redirection involved.

`curl -L -v --header \"something:special\” --cookie \"a=1;b=2\" --data \"param1&param2\"` https://url

### What I've tried

- Enabled the verbose mode via `-v`
- Enabled redirection via `-L`
- Checked for handshake (or common) errors
- Checked for typos and encoding issues
- Executed command within the `bash`
- Tried executing the command using a `Java` based approach
- Even tried to execute the command creating a `bash` from within the code and passing the command

### Java code

```
String command = "SOME CURL COMMAND USING POST"

// execute the command
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

// Since we will get a 302 (as expected), the result will be in the error stream
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getErrorStream());

// Do some formatting...
String tmp = "";
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  String t = scanner.next();
  if (t.equals("*") || t.equals("<") || t.equals(">")) {
    tmp += "\n";
  }
  tmp += t + " ";
}

System.out.println("Content" + tmp);
```

### Question

Is Java handling the execution differently? Because I don't see why I get a different result

Any help is appreciated.

Best

Comment: Java may use different curl - try to use absolute path to curl. Java curl may have been running with different env variables - maybe proxy - print and compare env variables.